# How did Dumbledore manage to hide the stone the way he did?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, philosophers-stone

The climax of the first book is when Harry is able to inexplicably able to retrieve the stone from inside the mirror. Shortly after, we learn that the **only** way to get the stone from the mirror, was to want to find it, but not use it. What does it mean for someone to put something inside the mirror? If you were to break the mirror, would you get the stone? I don't think so, then putting the stone inside the mirror, would be to put the stone **through** the mirror. Perhaps the stone is existing in wherever space we see Harry's family in the mirror. So that begs the question, how did Dumbledore put the stone in the mirror?

Comment: He's a wizard, and he used magic.

Comment: @jwodder Yes, but how exactly did he do it. Did he open a portal of some sort? How did he make sure that only the one who wanted to find it, but not use it, could have it?

Comment: [Avoid spoilers completely in the title.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/103122)

Comment: @Clockwork I think spoilers can be considered not spoilers 27 years after being released.. But a good edit nonetheless

Comment: @fez I tend to agree to some degree, as long as it's not in the title itself. At least imo

Comment: @Clockwork All three answers in the linked meta land on the poster's own personal policy, and that the site **does not have a policy**.

Comment: @Lexible To be perfectly honest, I really thought the votes counted as a community consensus in the event that there isn't an accepted answer

Comment: @Clockwork So by your own words is that community consensus is for the OP to use their own judgement, since all three answers in the meta post you linked more or less open with that position.

Comment: @Lexible No, I thought the highest voted answer was the community's last word. But if it isn't, then I ain't going to apply it anymore (even if I do like avoiding spoilers in titles).